# Two-way Communication with localhost C#

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-2013

I have a service running in the background as localhost. I need to connect to this service and start receiving/sending messages.

I can divide the whole task in 3 subtasks:

1. Establish communication
2. Assign a thread (T1) which is responsible for receiving messages from the localhost
3. Assign a thread (T2), which is responsible for sending messages to the localhost

**PROBLEM:**
Do I need a separate thread to monitor the connection? ***OR*** Can I call the `CreateClientConnectionSettings()` from `T1` and `T2` in case the connection gets lost (e.g. in case of service crash)

```
IPHostEntry ipHost;
IPAddress ipAddr;
IPEndPoint localEndPoint;
Socket clientSocket;

private void CreateClientConnectionSettings()
{
    // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket. 
    //This example  uses port 11111 on the local computer. 
    ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
    localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11111);

    // Creation TCP/IP Socket using Socket Class Costructor 
    clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        // Connect Socket to the remote endpoint using method Connect() 
        clientSocket.Connect(localEndPoint);
        UpdateConnectionStatusLabel( "Connected");
        //connectionStatusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        isConnected = true;
    }
    // Manage of Socket's Exceptions 
    catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
    {

        UpdateConnectionStatusLabel("ArgumentNullException" + ane.ToString());
    }

    catch (SocketException se)
    {

        UpdateConnectionStatusLabel("SocketException " + se.ToString());
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        UpdateConnectionStatusLabel("Unexpected exception : " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

**PS:** Is there any inbuilt classes for this functionality in C#?

Comment: You can only have one connections with the same Source IP, Destination IP, and port number.  Unless you use two different port number, you can have only one connection.

Comment: @jdweng: So, I must use a 3rd separate thread which keeps monitoring the connection status and tries to re-establish connection (if disconnected)? This 3rd thread will create the `clientSocket`, which other 2 threads can use for sending/receiving messages.

Comment: It isn't easy to determine when a connection fail.   The failure could be on other end of the connection.  The only real way of know is to send a message and see what gets returned.  That is why there is an option Keep_Alive which sends an empty message periodically and will report when there is no response.  TCP send an ACK for each message and the Keep_Alive will give an exception when the ACK is not returned.  Each message is is sent up to three times (when no ACK is received) at 5 seconds apart.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my limited experience, accessing the same socket from different threads is a very dangerous idea, but assuming that what you are making is a GUI client application, my suggestion would be to make a thread that establishes the connection, creates events when something arrives from the socket and sends data from a queue.

to encode the connection status you can create your own enum (outside the class but in the same namespace, even in the same file) for the relevant connection states like CONNECTED and DISCONNECTED:

```
public enum ConnStatus { CONNECTED, DISCONNECTED, FAULTED };
```

Then you can create a class that manages all of socket, thread, read/write ...
The thread will rise some events like "messageReceived" and "statusChanged", they have to be declared as fields of the class:

```
public delegate void StringEventHandler(string param);
public StringEventHandler messageReceived;
public delegate void ConnStatusEventHandler(ConnStatus param);
public ConnStatusEventHandler statusChanged;
```

then in the thread you can fire them like this:

```
try {

    clientSocket.Connect(localEndPoint);
    statusChanged?.Invoke(ConnStatus.CONNECTED);

    while(runThread){
        // Send messages in queue

        string RX = String.Empty;
        //READ from Socket
        //perform some basic checks if needed
        messageReceived?.Invoke(RX);
    }

    statusChanged?.Invoke(ConnStatus.DISCONNECTED);

catch {
    statusChanged?.Invoke(ConnStatus.FAULTED);
}
finally {
    //perform some cleanup
}
```

Comment: How can I get notified when a message arrives on the socket?